# Strange type error with basic operator overloading

Tags: swift, types, operator-overloading

I'm writing structs to represent vectors and matrices, with some operators to work with them. But some example usages of those operators produce type errors which I can't explain.

This is a reduced excrept from my library (`A` was a matrix type and `B` a vector type, for those interested):

```
struct A { }
struct B { }

func *(left: A, right: A) -> A { return A() }
func *(left: A, right: B) -> B { return B() }

let a: A = A()
let b: B = (a * a) * B()
```

Running this in a Swift Playground produces the following compiler error:

```
error: Test.playground:2:20: error: 'A' is not convertible to 'B'
let b: B = (a * a) * B()
           ~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Inlining some of the variables, extracting `a * a` as a separate variable and/or removing type annotations on from the variables in some cases either resolves the error or produces a different error.

I'm not looking for a workaround, I'm trying to understand what's going on here, whether I'm doing something wrong or whether I found a bug in the compiler.

I'm running Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Lol this also works: `{ a * a }() * B()` or `{ $0 * $0 }(a) * B()` :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. If we omit the type annotation (which
should not be necessary anyway):

```
let a = A()
let b = (a * a) * B()
```

then the compiler complains about "ambiguous use":

```
main.swift:14:12: error: ambiguous reference to member '*'
let b = (a * a) * B()
           ^
main.swift:7:6: note: found this candidate
func *(left: A, right: A) -> A { return A() }
     ^
main.swift:8:6: note: found this candidate
func *(left: A, right: B) -> B { return B() }
     ^
Swift.Float:4:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func *(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
                       ^
Swift.Double:4:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func *(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double

Swift.Float80:4:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func *(lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80) -> Float80
                       ^
Swift.UInt8:234:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func *(lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8) -> UInt8
                       ^
Swift.Int8:234:24: note: found this candidate
    public static func *(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8

// ... and many more  ...
```

which makes no sense, because those overloads are not applicable
to two `A` operands.

It seems that the compiler is "confused" because there are so many
overloaded definitions for the `*` operator. The problem does not
occur with a custom operator, this compiles without problems:

```
infix operator <*>: MultiplicationPrecedence

struct A { }
struct B { }

func <*>(left: A, right: A) -> A { return A() }
func <*>(left: A, right: B) -> B { return B() }

let a = A()
let b = (a <*> a) <*> B()
```

I recommend to file a bug at https://bugs.swift.org, and use intermediate 
variables:

```
let a = A()
let a2 = a * a
let b = a2 * B()
```

or intermediate casts:

```
let a = A()
let b = ((a * a) as A) * B()
```

as a workaround.

Comment: I think your observation about this bug not occurring when a custom operator is used is very interesting! Using intermediate casts seems like an okay-ish workaround for the use-cases I have. Thanks!